# Hover over container div is highlighting nested divs individually

Tags: hover

I am placing a "hover" feature on class `.one` (`.one :hover`) to change the `background-color` to grey. I am expecting it to highlight both `div`s (`.two, .three`) any time I hover over the container `.one` div.

However, what it does is hover over the two nested `div`s (`.two`, `.three`) individually.  Can someone please explain why this is so and what I have to do to make it highlight the entire div `.one` creating one single solid grey div?

Below is the CSS I used.

```css
.one {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two {
  background-color: rgba(0, 51, 102, 1);
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.three {
  background-color: rgba(0, 204, 204, 1);
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
}

.one :hover {
  background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
  <div class="three">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this CSS will help you:

```
.one:hover .two, .one:hover .three {
background-color: rgba(153,153,153,1);}
```

Comment: Thanks that is definitely the correct way to code it.  I have a question regarding the exact syntax of the css rule.  When using a singular ".one :hover" selector, there MUST be a space between .one and :hover. However, when you write the css rule with multiple selectors, there cannot be a space between .one and :hover. Is there any particular reason for that? It always saves me headaches later to understand why certain nuances exist opposed to just remembering that they are there.

Comment: It's sounds strange that you have to add a space between the selector and the pseudo-class. I never do so. If you look at e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp it doesn't look like it should be a space between.